# page transit animation control

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am creating a PageView section and it has around 5 - 10 children. I tried to make buttons to control the page flow.

```
IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
    onPressed: () {
        pageController.previousPage(
            duration: Duration(seconds:1), 
            curve: Curves.easeIn
        );
    }
)
```

**Edit:**
From flutter official documentation: [Flutter - Duration class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html)

> Constructors
> Duration({int days = 0, int hours = 0, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0, int milliseconds = 0, int microseconds = 0})
> Creates a new Duration object whose value is the sum of all individual parts.
> const

`Duration` includes `day/hour/minute/second/millisecond/microsecond` as its units when constructing a Duration class object.

If you want the pageController to have a shorter duration while going to some pages, you should assign a Duration with a smaller unit.

Comment: ctrl + space for intellisens on vscode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put it this way

```
pageController.previousPage(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), 
        curve: Curves.easeIn
    );
```

now it would take 0.2 secs to go next page